# How to run a script during start of an IIS service?

Tags: windows, iis

I have a site configured in IIS. I need to execute a script file(runAtStartup.bat) whenever my site is restarted. Usually we will restart from IIS only, but wanted to automate the execution of script file.

Comment: Please explain what have you tried so far?

Comment: Start of IIS services (like w3svc) is completely different from start of a web site on IIS. So you need to tell explicitly which one you want, or it is impossible to answer.

Comment: @LexLi I am looking for start of a web site on IIS. During that time, I need to run a batch script.

Comment: @Hima other than searching internet, nothing. I don't find options to do it.